# How to build a CAML query with where clause

Tags: sharepoint-designer, caml-query

I have this CAML below and i'm tring to do something like this.
Where username ='username' and id = 'id'

```
<Query>
     <Where>
         <And>
              <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='username'/>
                  <Value Type='Text'>" + username + "</Value>
              </Eq>
              <And>
                  <Eq>
                       <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                       <Value Type='Text'>" + ID + "</Value>
                  </Eq>
              </And>
         </And>
     </Where>
 </Query>
```

But it seems somehting is wrong with it.
Any ideas what i'm doing wrong and thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query SPUserField as SPLookupField

```
<Query> 
     <Where> 
         <And> 
              <Eq> 
                  <FieldRef Name='UserField'/> 
                  <Value Type='Lookup'>" + username + "</Value> 
              </Eq> 
              <Eq> 
                   <FieldRef Name='UserField' LookupId='True' /> 
                   <Value Type='Lookup'>" + ID + "</Value> 
              </Eq>
         </And> 
     </Where> 
 </Query>
```

Answer (score 7):

Your syntax is wrong, there's to many "Ands". I also prefer to lookup ID like IAfanasov says.

```
<Query> 
     <Where> 
         <And> 
              <Eq> 
                  <FieldRef Name='UserField'/> 
                  <Value Type='Lookup'>" + username + "</Value> 
              </Eq>
              <Eq> 
                   <FieldRef Name='UserField' LookupId='True' /> 
                   <Value Type='Lookup'>" + ID + "</Value> 
              </Eq>
         </And> 
     </Where> 
 </Query>
```

This is a nice starter/reference: http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<Query> </Query>` part from the text. Your CAML Query should begin with `<Where>` and end with `</Where>`

Try using the [U2U Caml Query builder](http://www.u2u.net/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) to test your CAML queries. OR simply use [Camlex.net](http://camlex.codeplex.com/) which would convert your CAML to .Net. Converting to .Net helps you analyzing expression errors in compile time itself.